# How can we draw on active screen using python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, graphics, drawing

I am creating an application in which can show anything (Text, Images, Shapes like circle, etc) I want on current/active screen whenever I want.
Current I created a code that can draw only on a canvas which I don't want to be created and drawings should be on active screen.
Even If we change the active window (alt+tab) the drawing should be there.
How can I achieve this using tkinter?
Or any other way if not possible with tkinter.
My current Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.create_line(x,y,"abcd")
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not possible with tkinter. Asking for recommendations for other libraries is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Changed the topic for question. If you have any other options to achieve this then please share.